# Days diff based on selected date from succeeding row

Tags: mysql, subquery

How can I get the succeeding or previous data row result from a query, as I wanted to compute days difference based on date_created for succeeding rows?

```
SELECT 
    -- *,
    h.date_created,
    -- (select date_created where id = h.id and pci_s = h.pci_s + 1) as dc,
    h.id,
    h.date_created,
    CONCAT('B', h.pci_b) AS batch,
    h.pci_s,
    DATEDIFF(h.date_created, h.date_created) as days_in_stage
FROM
    historical h
WHERE
    h.pci_b = 1
;
```

Expected

```
date_created    id  date_created    batch   pci_s   days_in_stage
2021-07-18T06:32:26Z    1   2021-07-18T06:32:26Z    B1  0   0
2021-07-20T06:32:26Z    4   2021-07-20T06:32:26Z    B1  1   2
```

Here's the jsfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32a242/3

Currently using: Mysql 5.7.33

Comment: MySQL8 and MySQL5.x have different functionality.  Please could you edit your question to clarify which version you're using?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: thanks ! added version as 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the succeeding or  previous data row result

that you are looking for `LEAD` or `LAG` window function.

but your MySQL version is lower than 8.0 which didn't support window function.

you can try to use a subquery to make `LEAD` or `LAG` window function.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    h.date_created,
    h.id,
    h.date_created,
    CONCAT('B', h.pci_b) AS batch,
    h.pci_s,
    COALESCE(DATEDIFF(h.date_created,(
        SELECT hh.date_created
        FROM historical hh
        WHERE h.pci_b = hh.pci_b AND h.date_created > hh.date_created
        ORDER BY hh.date_created DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )),0) as days_in_stage
FROM
    historical h
WHERE
    h.pci_b = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32a242/20/0)**:

```
|         date_created | id |         date_created | batch | pci_s | days_in_stage |
|----------------------|----|----------------------|-------|-------|---------------|
| 2021-07-18T06:32:26Z |  1 | 2021-07-18T06:32:26Z |    B1 |     0 |             0 |
| 2021-07-20T06:32:26Z |  4 | 2021-07-20T06:32:26Z |    B1 |     1 |             2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL8 you can simply use `LAG()` or `LEAD()` window functions.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

With MySQL5.x you don't have that so can instead use correlated-sub-queries, for example...

```
SELECT 
    -- *,
    (SELECT date_created FROM historical WHERE date_created < h.date_created ORDER BY date_Created DESC LIMIT 1)  AS prev_date_created,
    -- (select date_created where id = h.id and pci_s = h.pci_s + 1) as dc,
    h.id,
    h.date_created,
    CONCAT('B', h.pci_b) AS batch,
    h.pci_s,
    DATEDIFF(h.date_created, h.date_created) as days_in_stage
FROM
    historical h
WHERE
    h.pci_b = 1
ORDER BY
    h.date_created
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ce3b601688e1de11eda1007bffea9f9

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of mysql you can use Lead and Lag functions for getting next row and previous row data. But if you are not using current version then this will not work, there is other solution.

Please share your mysql version if not using new version.

For eg for new version:

```
SELECT 
    -- *,
    h.date_created,
    -- (select date_created where id = h.id and pci_s = h.pci_s + 1) as dc,
    h.id,
    h.date_created,
    CONCAT('B', h.pci_b) AS batch,
    h.pci_s,
    DATEDIFF(h.date_created, h.date_created) as days_in_stage, 
    lead(h.date_created)over (order by h.date_created) next_row_date,
    lag(h.date_created)over (order by h.date_created) pre_row_date
FROM
    historical h
WHERE
    h.pci_b = 1
;
```